# Commercials are on TV,or on the channel

Tags: word-usage

Can I use:
Commercials are on the TV right now

Commercials are on Channel XYZ.

Does "on" sound natural?

Answer (score 0):

It would sound more natural to say "There are commercials on TV right now," or "There are commercials on Channel XYZ." "There are" indicates the existence of something. Without "there are" the sentences sound a little weird to me.

"On" is the correct preposition. I think "on TV" sounds better than "on the TV". When you use "the," it sounds like you're talking about some specific TV set. When you use "on TV" without the "the," it more accurately gets across the idea that something is being aired on any given TV. Which is the case when you're speaking about  a broadcast network.